# How to unmarshal dynamic XML data to struct?

Tags: xml, go, struct, xml-parsing, unmarshalling

I have a XML data which has some repeated data with dynamic element name as shown below.

```
<Ht>
<Criteria>
    <ADNode_1>2</ADNode_1>
    <CDNode_1>2</CDNode_1>
    <IFNode_1>0</IFNode_1>
    <ADNode_2>2</ADNode_2>
    <CDNode_2>0</CDNode_2>
    <IFNode_2>0</IFNode_2>
    <ADNode_3>0</ADNode_3>
    <CDNode_3>0</CDNode_3>
    <IFNode_3>0</IFNode_3>
</Criteria>
<session id="1056134770841202228344907">
    <Htd ID="21170">
        <Data_1>
            <Info Count="2"></Info>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B2/R1">
                <Type>TR1</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B3/R1">
                <Type>TR1</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B4/R1">
                <Type>TR1</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B6/R1">
                <Type>TR1</Type>
            </Data>
        </Data_1>
        <Data_2>
            <Info Count="2"></Info>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B2/R1">
                <Type>TR2</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B3/R1">
                <Type>TR2</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B4/R1">
                <Type>TR2</Type>
            </Data>
            <Data Id="iV29308/B6/R1">
                <Type>TR3</Type>
            </Data>
        </Data_2>
    </Htd>
</session>
```

I can create individual structs for `<ADNode_1>` ,`<ADNode_2>` and `<ADNode_3>` or `<Data_1>`, `<Data_2>` but there can be n number of these nodes.
Like below

```
<ADNode_1>2</ADNode_1>
<ADNode_2>2</ADNode_2>
<ADNode_3>2</ADNode_3>
<ADNode_n>2</ADNode_n>
```

OR

```
<Data_1></Data_1>
<Data_2></Data_2>
<Data_3></Data_3>
<Data_n></Data_n>
```

How can I create struct for these nodes to have n number of nodes or elements?

Here is the playground [link](https://go.dev/play/p/Bav9IVouawW) I am trying to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for these situations you may use a slice in Go to "gather" the elements, and use the `,any` option to put everything in it you don't have a mapping for. To be able to identify the source, use an `XMLName xml.Name` field which will retain the name of the XML tag it originates from.

For example you may model your XML like this:

```
type Ht struct {
    Criteria struct {
        Nodes []struct {
            XMLName xml.Name
            Content string `xml:",chardata"`
        } `xml:",any"`
    }
    Session struct {
        ID  string `xml:"id,attr"`
        Htd struct {
            ID    string `xml:"ID,attr"`
            DataX []struct {
                XMLName xml.Name
                Info    struct {
                    Count int `xml:"Count,attr"`
                }
                DataNodes []struct {
                    XMLName xml.Name
                    ID      string `xml:"Id,attr"`
                    Type    string
                } `xml:",any"`
            } `xml:",any"`
        }
    } `xml:"session"`
}
```

Parsing it and reencoding it will retain all elements:

```
var ht Ht
if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &ht); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

result, err := xml.MarshalIndent(ht, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(result))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1HRpaXtM3Up)):

```
<Ht>
  <Criteria>
    <ADNode_1>2</ADNode_1>
    <CDNode_1>2</CDNode_1>
    <IFNode_1>0</IFNode_1>
    <ADNode_2>2</ADNode_2>
    <CDNode_2>0</CDNode_2>
    <IFNode_2>0</IFNode_2>
    <ADNode_3>0</ADNode_3>
    <CDNode_3>0</CDNode_3>
    <IFNode_3>0</IFNode_3>
  </Criteria>
  <session id="1056134770841202228344907">
    <Htd ID="21170">
      <Data_1>
        <Info Count="2"></Info>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B2/R1">
          <Type>TR1</Type>
        </Data>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B3/R1">
          <Type>TR1</Type>
        </Data>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B4/R1">
          <Type>TR1</Type>
        </Data>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B6/R1">
          <Type>TR1</Type>
        </Data>
      </Data_1>
      <Data_2>
        <Info Count="2"></Info>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B2/R1">
          <Type>TR2</Type>
        </Data>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B3/R1">
          <Type>TR2</Type>
        </Data>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B4/R1">
          <Type>TR2</Type>
        </Data>
        <Data Id="iV29308/B6/R1">
          <Type>TR3</Type>
        </Data>
      </Data_2>
    </Htd>
  </session>
</Ht>
```